# jQuery UI slider doesn't seem to render?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slider, jquery-ui-slider

I may be missing something completely obvious here but when I call `$("#zoom_slider").slider()` I get no slider appear.

If you goto [this url](http://www.coverdude.com/jcovers.html) you can replicate the issue by click on any of the images in the main window, this will then load a larger image (currently of a watch).  The slider should appear to the top right underneath where it says "Zoom" but it does not...

I include the jQuery UI from google via this call:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure, but what I would try to do would be to put all of your script declarations in the `<head></head>` section of your HTML. Also, make sure you are using the most up to date versions of jQuery UI and jQuery.